# UICollectionViewController with Flow Layout Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I've just created a `UICollectionViewController` programatically. Up to here everything is fine but I'm facing some problems. My app immediately crashes when the CollectionViewController is called, returning this error.

> 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

I tried to insert `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` of course, but it continues to crash and I do not understand why. Can someone explain to me how to use a `UICollectionViewController` without using the storyboard ??

Where am I doing wrong?

```
@implementation ChooseRegion

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your collectionview?

Comment: @ReinierMelian you can't just call a method over an object without initializing it. Sh_Khan's answer is the only correct way.

Comment: Does your `UICollectionView` come from a Storyboard? Or are you creating it programmatically?

Comment: @AlejandroIván Without Storyboard

Comment: item size is nil

Comment: @ReinierMelian you're not. You are just allocating memory, but you never call `init` or `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:`.

Comment: Can you please post the method where you are creating the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I'm edit my question with all code of my collectionViewController.m

Comment: u forget direction

Comment: So your view controller is actually a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`? Make it a subclass of `UIViewController`, since `UICollectionViewController` already has a `UICollectionView` automatically embedded.

Comment: oops don't have to create a Coll inside controller

Comment: @AlejandroIván. if I render uicollectionViewcontroller a UIViewController I should create a new collectionView object and insert it in the viewcontroller .. I want to use collectionViewController because I already needed all the movement of its scrollView

Comment: @Sh_Khan i dont understand

Comment: inside collectionViewController don't create a collectionView actually it's designated with it set it parameteres only all we talked about expecting you create it inside a UIViewController subclass

Comment: I may not be able to use a collectionViewController anymore.. its incredible

Comment: see here https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: @Sh_Khan this link use storyboard... I not need of storyboard... the implementation of uicollectionViewController programmatically is equal to link

Comment: then subclass UIViewController .....

Comment: @Sh_Khan solved!.. I put my answer with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved my problem ... Thank you all for the many tips and suggestions you gave me in this .. you were very kind !!**

all this problem occurs because the `UICollectionViewController` is not initialized with its layout at the time of its presentation.

I call `UICollectionViewController` from another `UIViewController` using the `[self presentViewController:collectionViewController animated:YES completion:nil]` method .... At this point the problem occurs ...

The `UICollectionViewController` was only allocated to be presented and did not have the necessary layout to be shown ... that's why this damn crash !!!

**So I solved this way**

**UIViewController.m**

```
-(void)presentCollectionViewController {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout * layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake (100, 100);
    [layout setScrollDirection: UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    
    UICollectionViewController * chooseRegion = [[UICollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];

    [self presentViewController: chooseRegion animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

**UICollectionViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

}
```

At this point everything works ...

Inside the UICollectionViewController you do not need to specify any type of layout in this case, as it is specified during the allocation of the class before its presentation

Answer (score 1):

If you're using (or have subclassed) a `UICollectionViewController`, it already has a `UICollectionView` instance assigned. You don't need to instantiate or create a new one. I suspect the reason this isn't working is because you aren't adding the new view to the hierarchy (even though you're assigning it to `self.collectionView`.

Instead of `self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] init...`

Just assign the layout to your existing `UICollectionView`, eg:

`self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout`